# Wordpress's favicon with custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, class, favicon

I'm building a website with wordpress and I'm struggling with the favicon. Here's the problem: let's say that, for some reason, you want to write your code in the backend (using the only static code, for example, if you need to add some php directly in your page, or some javascript) using a custom template.
It is probably not a good habit, but let's say that you want to add a class to the body (for styling purpose) like that:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Your template
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
?>
<body <?php body_class( 'your-class' ); ?>>

    <?php get_header(); ?>
```

You will generate a code like that:

```
<body class="your-class some-other-class">

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-CA" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <OTHER THINGS>
</head>
<body class="all-the-other-class">
```

So here's the problem. I just want to add a new class to the body, in the body tag and I want to avoid to create a new body tag at the top of the code, before the html declaration. And I want to do for a single template because, in this way, I can easily add some php and some javascript directly in my static html.
To be clear, the code that I wrote, even if it's not tidy and it's technically wrong, it works fine but the drawback is that you can't see the favicon on the page where you add the body_class function. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
<?php  
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
    return array_merge( $classes, array( 'whatever' ) );
} );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `body` tag before the `get_header()`, so this will render before the header tags.

What you need to do, is to edit the the `header.php` template file, and update it here instead.

Comment: The header php file will be called in all the files so, if I edit the very file and I'll add, for example <body <?php body_class( 'myclass' ); ?>>, I will have the tag my class on all my pages. I want to create a custom template to have a different template, which is, in WordPress logic, a different page